# Eclipse Gurus: where can I find information to make a theme for the IDE? (I wish similar to Chrome)

Tags: eclipse, themes

I suppose that similar to Chrome is impossible as all window api are not designed to make the wonderful cool effect of Chrome. However where can I start to make a theme for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this could easily be done with Eclipse 3.x.

But with e4 (Eclipse4), this would be easier [through CSS styling](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Running_CSS_demos):

[image]

That plus [gradient effect](https://toedter.com/2009/05/28/e4-css-styling-fun-with-gradients/) can lead to pretty cool GUI:

[image]

Comment: Thank You, very cool! who knows if the file menu would be totally hiddenable